# Login attempt with Fetch API failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I am trying to build a web scraper using the Fetch API but the code below that I have written will always say that I need to put password and username, Did I do anything wrong?

```
fetch('http://quotes.toscrape.com/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Accept: "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({username:"myusername", password:"mysecretpassword"}),
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.text()
        })
        .then(html => {
            console.log(html)
        })
```

Comment: I think you don't need JSON.stringify over there

Comment: @Ibrahim Whether I put JSON.stringify or not, it still doesn't work

Comment: It's hard to help you, when you put in a dummy url so we can't find the docs and don't provide the response from the server.

Comment: @Enslev Hello, I have edited the post, it seems my code won't work on any website even the practice site I updated to, help would be appreciated

Comment: use new FormData()  instead of JSON.stringify

Comment: @AbdelrahmanM.Allam Still does nothing, the website returns a response that says please input username

Comment: You are trying to post to a web page containing a login form. That is not how it works.
If you want to log in in that way they need to have an API through which you can authenticate.
Even if you did send correct request to this page, it would stop you since it couldn't validate CSRF token, which is a good thing.
quotes.toscrape.com is built in a way so that you can scrape the content with a webscraper, not so you can use it in the way you intent.

Comment: @Enslev Hello, CSRF token can be scraped inside a hidden HTML input and then put into a POST request, I have done several web scraping tasks that require login and yes, most of the sites do have CSRF protection, but I still can get through it without a problem. Unfortunately I wasn't using the fetch API but instead I used requests (I need to use fetch API on current situation) and I am aware of the difference between a webservice and webscraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved,
I only needed to change the body with params whose value is

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('username', 'usersname123')
params.append('password', 'userspassword123')
```